# GET variable not being accessed

Tags: php, get, request

I have a simple *7 lined* `PHP`script, as shown below:

## Code

```
require( "connect.php" );
$ctg = ($_GET['ctg'])? $_GET['ctg']:'movie';
$offset = ($_GET['off'])? $_GET['off']:30;
$query = "SELECT `msg`, `id`, `nick`, `date` FROM `entries` WHERE `ctg` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET ?";
$statemnt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$statemnt->bindParam( 1, $ctg, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$statemnt->bindParam( 2, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$statemnt->execute();
$results = $statemnt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
echo "$ctg\n$offset\n" . count($results) . "\n";
```

## Problem

The problem I am facing is like this: When I execute the file in console(using `php fetch.php`), all the `echo` work great. When I open the page in browser with no `$_GET` variables, the same output is observed.

The output in browser is the same when I provide it with just the `ctg` indexed-variable(such as `http://localhost/fetch.php?ctg=docu`) the output is correct; like this:

```
docu
30
15
```

But when I pass the `off` index-variable(either as *`fetch.php?off=15`* **OR** *`fetch.php?ctg=docu&off=15`* **OR** *`fetch.php?off=15&ctg=docu`*); The output is always like this:

```
docu
15
0
```

## Question

The output(and `var_dump`) both show correct values being passed to both variables, then why is the PDO statement not receiving any results? Why does the `count($results)` remain **0**?

Any help is appreciated.

---

## PS

I also included the following statement:

```
$statemnt->debugDumpParams();
```

which dumps this in browser(and console):

```
SQL: [102] SELECT `msg`, `id`, `nick`, `date` FROM `entries` WHERE `ctg` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET ?
Params:  2
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
```

Comment: Do you have enough records to handle an offset of 15? If there's only 14 records, you'll get nothing back because you've specified an offset that's larger than the available data.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, I have more than 7000 records for `ctg=docu`

Comment: Also, it returns me proper results when no values are passed in `$_GET`(as you can see, it output **30** for that and fetches 15 results too.

Comment: Try to disable `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, might be related to PDO type coercion still.

Comment: @mario Post that as answer. Adding `conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );` solved the trouble.

Comment: Also, explicitly cast your offset to an INT `$offset = (isset($_GET['off'])) ? (int) $_GET['off'] : 30;`

Comment: Then it's one of those bugs again. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47960 -- The explicit `int` casting is the better option then.

Comment: hmm, I never had to do this type conversion before. I thought that is why `PDO` and `bindParam` were introduced. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the `$off` `GET` variable is being treated as a string whereas `int` is expected

Change:

```
$offset = ($_GET['off'])? $_GET['off']:30;
```

to

```
$offset = ($_GET['off'])?(intval($_GET['off']):30;
```

Of course proper validation should exist for all your `GET`variables